# Synthetic Function "##" in scala

Tags: scala

I recently saw some code like this code:

```
val x: Any = "a"
val y = x.## // y: Int = 97
```

Well, ok the output is just the ASCI value of 'a', but lets have a look at

```
List(1,2).## // Int = 985731359
List(1,2).toString.## // Int = 1063384434
```

My IDE tells about '##' that it is a  'Synthetic Function'. So what is ## doing and what is a Synthetic Function?

Comment: I think its just short for `hashCode`.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's basically an alias of `hashCode`, with a couple of notable exceptions that make it somewhat safer:

> Equivalent to `x.hashCode` except for boxed numeric types and `null`. For numerics, it returns a hash value which is consistent with value equality: if two value type instances compare as true, then ## will produce the same hash value for each of them. For `null` returns a hashcode where `null.hashCode` throws a `NullPointerException`.

(source: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html###:Int)

Examples:

**normal value**

```
scala> val x: Any = "a"
x: Any = a

scala> x.hashCode
res2: Int = 97

scala> x.##
res3: Int = 97
```

**null value**

```
scala> null.hashCode
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 33 elided

scala> null.##
res5: Int = 0
```

---

A synthetic field, instead, is a field generated by the compiler to work around the underlying JVM limitations, especially when dealing with inner anonymous classes, a concept extraneous to the JVM.

Here's a good explanation of what it means in details: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-synthetic-class-method-field/