# What does ## documentation mean by "boxed numeric"?

Tags: scala

What do the scala [docs for `Any@##`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any@##():Int) mean when they say "*boxed numeric types*" <sup>†</sup>?

The quote from the docs is (highlighting mine):

> Equivalent to `x.hashCode` except for **boxed numeric types** and null. **For numerics**, it returns ...

1. I assume that "*for numerics*" should read "*for **boxed** numerics*"?
2. What is a *boxed numeric* - do they mean `Boxed[Int]`, for example?

This question came about after reading [Synthetic Function “##” in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32054844/5065475)

<sup>†</sup> *I thought that a [value type is a subtype of `scala.AnyVal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyVal) and is not implemented as an object, therefore is not boxed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hashCode` method is defined for `java.lang.Object` (or `scala.AnyRef`) but has no equivalent for primitive ("unboxed") types. When you call `hashCode` on a primitive, you'll have the hash-code of the boxed type, e.g.

```
3.0.hashCode  // 1074266112
```

Here 3.0 is autoboxed to `java.lang.Double`, thus providing the `hashCode` method.

Scala adds `##` to allow correct comparison of primitives, e.g.

```
3 == 3.0   // true
```

This is because `##` is different from the hash-code here:

```
3.0.##  // 3 !
```

For reference values, `##` behaves the same as `hashCode`:

```
"foo".##       // 101574
"foo".hashCode // 101574
```

Comment: Thank you. In the context of my original questions are you therefore saying: "*for numerics*" should be interpreted as "*for numerics (boxed or otherwise)*"; and *boxed numeric types* specifically means the `java.lang` primitive-wrapper types that are subtypes of `java.lang.Number`? Doesn't scala target environments other than the JVM? What is the meaning of a "boxed numeric type" there?

Comment: Yes and yes. For example in JS - http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/ - `println(3.0.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].hashCode)` will give you 3.

Comment: From what I can see from javap `##` also autoboxes the double literal in the JVM before calling a utility method to get the result. That all makes sense now, thank you.